# bootstrap number of columns based on parent columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, less

Does anyone know if this can be accomplished with bootstrap mixins.

**columns( number of parent)**

Something like what [Neat](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#span-columns) has.

In Neat the Columns mixins works like these

```
@mixin span-columns($span, $display: block) { ... }
```

Where $span can be **3** or something like **3 of 12**

> Specifies the number of columns an element should span. If the
>   selector is nested the number of columns of its parent element should
>   be passed as an argument as well.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When i understand your  question well you should read [Less mixins and variables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less).

You will find the mixins to generate semantic grid columns in the `less/mixins/grid.less` file of Bootstrap's source code.

To generate a div that overspans 3 columns you should use for instance:

```
div.three{
.make-xs-column(3);
}
```

Notice the mobile first nature of these mixins. With the above code the `xs` mixin generate CSS code which will be applied for all screen width (no media queries).

When using:

```
div.three{
.make-xs-column(6);
.make-sm-column(3);
}
```

You div will overspan 6 columns for screen width below the 768 pixels (the`xs` grid) and 3 columns above the 768 pixels, the `sm` grid and up (explicit calling the larger grid mixins is not needed unless you want to overspan a difference number of columns). It's inportant to start the mixins for the smaller grids before the larger grids, see also: [Bootstrap 3 mixin multiple make-*-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448284/bootstrap-3-mixin-multiple-make-column/26700395)

Comment: Bass thanks for your time and answer. What I'am looking for is a mixin where I can specify the number of columns based on the columns of a parent (this would be used with nested grids). In NEAT you simply specify 3 of 12, 4 of 8, etc.

thanks

Comment: oh okay, than it seems that the only option will to use something like `div.parent {.make-xs-column(6); div { .make-row(); div {.make-xs-column(6);}}}` Notice that nesting again divides the parent in twelve columns, see also http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting.

Comment: Exactly, and nesting make you make the calculations so that you can rearrange everything based on the top level grid. In NEAt you simply specify N of Parent and that's it.