# Bootstrap grid is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to create a page layout using bootstrap. My layout something similar to below image.

[image]

To archive for this I tried using bootstrap grid fuctions.

This is how my `html` look like

```
  <div class="myLayout">
    <div class="col-1">
    </div>    
    <div class="col-2">
    </div>    
    <div class="col-3">
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my `less` file

```
.myLayout {
  .make-row();
  
  .col-1 {
    .make-md-column(6);
    .make-sm-column(7);
    .make-xs-column(12);
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
  }  
  
  .col-2 {
    .make-md-column(3);
    .make-sm-column(5);
    .make-xs-column(6);
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
  }  
 
  .col-3 {
    .make-md-column(3);
    .make-sm-column(0);
    .make-xs-column(6);
    .visible-lg-block;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This is generating CSS from about `Less`

```
.col-1 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
    background: black;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-1 {
    height: 292px;
  }
}

.col-2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
    background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-2 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-2 {
    float: left;
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-2 {
    height: 292px;
  }
}

.col-3 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  display: none !important;
    background: red;
  height: 100px;
    
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-3 {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

But this is not working for my expecting result. Can somebody tell me what is wrong in my code?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not convinced that 0 is an acceptable value for the `make-sm-column()` mixin in .col3

Comment: What does the final output of your LESS file look like?

Comment: @Joe Yes dear, I tried removing it. but not working. Only displaying first 2 columns in every screen sizes.

Comment: @hungerstar Only first 2 columns in every screen sizes

Comment: I want to display red color column in large desktop size only.

Comment: do you need support for ie <=10?

Comment: not important.. But if it is, its good

Comment: Why not just use the existing bootstrap classes, rather than re-make the columns in your own styles? (ie: give the first column a class of `col-1 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-12`?

Comment: @hungerstar I updated answer with creating CSS

Comment: Your `.make-*-column` order is incorrect (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27442489/2712740).

Answer (score 5):

There shouldn't be any need for custom CSS/LESS code to make this happen. **You can do it with the existing Bootstrap grid system classes.**

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/Ad8CXAfX7F)**

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
}
.first {
  background-color: black;
}
.second {
  background-color: blue;
}
.third {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="first col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="second col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="third col-lg-3 visible-lg-inline"></div>
```

Comment: I changed your code to a code snippet so you don't have to rely on bootply (as it seems to be down now and quite often).

Comment: Yeah, saw the notification come through. I'll have to look into that more. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, its working.. But I want to keep my markup clean without using more classes and IDs. Thats why I am using CSS/LESS to make this happen

Comment: going through your classes I tried again changing my `less` but then its not working

Comment: @TNK And yet by wanting that, you're making your LESS more complicated than it has to be. You're literally favoring messy, needlessly complicated LESS code in an effort to keep the HTML a bit cleaner. Don't reinvent the wheel, and don't do more work than you have to in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: @TNK that's a flawed and dangerous way of thinking. classes and ids don't make markup _dirty_. They have a job of identifying elements so they can be referred to in other resources. Furthermore, you shouldn't be loading a fairly heavy frontend framework if you're worried about the amount of classes you'll be using